# Find all files with a filename beginning with a specified string?

Tags: bash, find

I have a directory with roughly 100000 files in it, and I want to perform some function on all files beginning with a specified string, which may match tens of thousands of files.

I have tried

```
ls mystring*
```

but this returns with the bash error 'Too many arguments'.  My next plan was to use

```
find ./mystring* -type f
```

but this has the same issue.

The code needs to look something like

```
for FILE in `find ./mystring* -type f`
do
    #Some function on the file
done
```

Comment: Instead of a `for` loop, you should pipe `find` into `while`.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905054/11725753)

Answer (score 417, accepted):

Use `find` with a wildcard:

```sh
find . -name 'mystring*'
```

Comment: and to execute some function  "find . -name 'mystring*' -exec [command]" for example delete "find . -name 'mystring*' -exec rm {} \;"

Comment: Where {} is a placeholder for file name :-)  (so you can construct your own actions)

Comment: This seems to return all results *containing* the string? The

Comment: ...or `find . -iname 'mystring*'` for case insensitive search.

Comment: OP refers to a single directory so insert `-maxdepth 1` before the `-name` to limit find to the current folder

Comment: @jacanterbury: it is not clear if this directory contains other directories (besides the 100k files). It it doesn't, this is not needed. But thanks, might be useful to someone.

Comment: @eldar I've used this, and realize that I admittedly still don't know what the \; does. Any easy explanation for future readers?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am using If condition but not working.  if [[ find /tmp/home/my_location -name 'mystring*'.ctl ]]

Comment: it would be nice if this were the default, i.e. I could just find anything in the current directory + subdirectories by typing `find my_file`, I always forget this syntax...

Answer (score 34):

```
ls | grep "^abc"
```

will give you all files **beginning** (which is what the OP specifically required) with the substring`abc`.
It operates only on the current directory whereas `find` operates recursively into sub folders.

To use `find` for only files **starting** with your string try

> find . -name 'abc'*

Comment: Don't use ls | grep. Use a glob or a for loop with a condition to allow non-alphanumeric filenames, see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2010

Comment: "Don't use" is perhaps a little directive. 'ls /directory/*mystring*' will drill down to sub-directories which you may not want to do, and using glob and loops is more complicated. Granted the ls | grep approach has weaknesses however its simplicity makes it an attractive solution for some people and in some situations.

Comment: Yes, "be careful when using ls | grep" is perhaps better. But I was just quoting the shell check rule.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to restrict your search only to files you should consider to use `-type f` in your search

try to use also `-iname` for case-insensitive search

Example:

```
find /path -iname 'yourstring*' -type f
```

---

You could also perform some operations on results without pipe sign or xargs

Example:

Search for files and show their size in MB

```
find /path -iname 'yourstring*' -type f -exec du -sm {} \;
```