# How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?

Tags: linux, shell

How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?

Answer (score 4243, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -name "foo*"
```

`find` needs a starting point, so the `.` (dot) points to the current directory.

If you need **case insensitive** search use :

```
find . -iname "foo*"
```

Comment: I know this is tagged as linux but this is worth mentioning: the path is required for on other *nix variants that aren't linux.  On linux, the path is optional if you want to use dot.

Comment: @Seatter "foo*" tells find to look for all files that start with "foo".  It is just his example.  You could use "gpio*" to find all files who's names start with gpio, or just "gpio1" to find all files named gpio1.

Comment: * is a wildcard - more wildcard possibilities here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Comment: note that the "foo*" is in quotes so the shell doesn't expand it before passing it to find. if you just did `find . foo*`, the `foo*` would be expanded AND THEN passed to find.

Comment: use -iname for case insensitive

Comment: I have a file test.xml in the subdirectory of my current working directory and I have used the command find . -name "test*". It doesnt work.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when put in a sh script. Does it need bash or something?

Comment: Worth stressing that `" "` is very necessary for recursive searching.

Comment: Also useful: If you don't want to be notified about directories you don't have permission to (or other errors), you can do `find . -name "foo*" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: If you wish to ignore case (as in most cases when I use this) then you could do: 
find . -iname "foo*"

Comment: In reponse to @IslandCow's comment: that's not true (at least not everywhere). I have to use '.' explicitly on my Fedora boxes.

Comment: @WesternGun Can you explain why the `" "` is needed? What is "expansion" and why is that bad?

Comment: @KolobCanyon you can check the man page of find, or [this link](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and search the word "non-bug" and then "quote", there you have more info. Also, check [this](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php). Generally, `*` expansion is "iterate current dir and substitute the * with every file name". So, to avoid this, we use quotes.

Comment: @WesternGun Is that different than string interpolation? Because I thought quotes meant string interpolation in the shell

Comment: @KolobCanyon something like that, but the links have more and I think expansion is broader.

Comment: This is ridiculous... what if I only want to search in the current dir??

Comment: @yan king yin - use `ls`?

Comment: weirdly enough this doesn't work me. What worked for me is the answer from Paul Whipp

Comment: If I leave out the quotes, it searches only in the current directory.  The genius designer of this should explain the behavior.

Comment: dot does not work for me, I have to use `find /some/path/  -iname "foo*"`

Comment: note that sometime subdirectories are sym-linked, and to traverse those you need to include -L option

Comment: ag -g <pattern>  / is better (because multi threading).

Comment: If you want only files **without the directories**, use [`-type f`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052661/9157799)

Comment: It seems that this does not work when I am looking for wildcard expanding in the full path name. Say I am looking for files such that the full path matches `string1*string2*`, for example `/home/string1bla/string2.txt`, how would I do this?

Comment: To answer my own question above. Use the `-path` option, see https://superuser.com/a/400086/728074.

Answer (score 315):

Piping *[find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))* into *[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)* is often more convenient; it gives you the full power of regular expressions for arbitrary wildcard matching.

For example, to find all files with case insensitive string "foo" in the filename:

```
find . -print | grep -i foo
```

Comment: `find` also has the `-iname`, `-regex`, and `-iregex` flags for case-insensitive wildcard, regex, and case-insensitive regex matching, so piping to `grep` is unnecessary.

Comment: I don't think it is about being unnecessary, but being more convenient.

Comment: However, piping to grep -v can allow you to use simple strings or regexes to remove entries you don't want.

Comment: @iobender - Sadly, I can tell you from experience that not all systems come with a `find` command that supports those options.  Sometimes `grep` becomes the only option.

Comment: One important caveat here is that if you're using find on a directory that contains A LOT of files (eg; `\`) then this can be quite slow.

Comment: Works great. Didn't expect answer to `foo` but got answers: `Fooled Around`, `Fool Would Say`, `Fool's Overture`, `Devil's Food`, `Foo Fighters`, `Foot In The Door` and `Fooling Yourself` :)

Answer (score 220):

`find` will find all files that match a pattern:

```
find . -name "*foo"
```

However, if you want a picture:

```
tree -P "*foo"
```

Comment: `brew install tree` for Mac OSX users w/o `apt-get` installed

Comment: Tested on macOS Sierra, just add '--print' -> ' find . name "*foo" --print '  .
http://superuser.com/questions/177289/searching-mac-through-terminal

Comment: sudo yum install tree -y for CentOS

Answer (score 109):

### [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

In case `find` is too slow, try the `fd` utility - a simple and fast alternative to `find` written in [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29).

Syntax:

```
fd PATTERN
```

Demo:

[image]

Homepage: https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Comment: I went to the GitHub link to get the details on it, but it would be worthwhile to edit your post and mention why `fd` is faster than `find`. The reason: "Very fast due to parallelized directory traversal"

Answer (score 81):

```
find -L . -name "foo*"
```

In a few cases, I have needed the -L parameter to handle symbolic directory links.  By default symbolic links are ignored.  In those cases it was quite confusing as I would change directory to a sub-directory and see the file matching the pattern but find would not return the filename.  Using -L solves that issue.  The symbolic link options for find are -P -L -H

Comment: L switch is very helpful. Many times user do not have any idea about underlying directories, whether they are softlinked or are normal directories. So in case of doubt, it always good to use L option. At least, it has always helped me.

Answer (score 73):

Use

```
find <directory_path>  -type f -name "<wildcard-match>"
```

In the wildcard-match you can provide the string you wish to match, e.g., *.c (for all C files).

Comment: Your answer is the first most correct here as it only searches files as specified. The others not specifying type will return directories.

Comment: if you wish to search for a directory "-type f" could be changed to "-type d "

Comment: By default, `find` detect symbolic **file** links (but not the ones in symbolic **directory** links). `-type f` will cause `find` to not detect symbolic **file** links. If you also want to include symlinks that point to a file, use [`-L`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646309/9157799): `find -L <optional_directory_path> -type f`. Don't use `-type f,l` since it will also include symbolic **directory** links.

Answer (score 63):

If your shell supports [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (can be enabled by: `shopt -s globstar`), you can use:

```
echo **/*foo*
```

to find any files or folders recursively. This is supported by Bash 4, zsh and similar shells.

---

Personally I've got this shell function defined:

```
f() { find . -name "*$1*"; }
```

<sup>Note: Above line can be pasted directly to shell or added into your user's `~/.bashrc` file.</sup>

Then I can look for any files by typing:

```
f some_name
```

Alternatively you can use a [`fd` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50840902/55075) with a simple syntax, e.g. `fd pattern`.

Comment: This just goes into a single level. Not recursing into the sub directories for me

Comment: @Broncha Because you need to activate the extended globbing by `shopt -s globstar` command. This is supported in Bash, zsh and similar shells.

Comment: `bash-3.2$ shopt -s globstar`
gives
`bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`

Comment: @drewish You need to upgrade your Bash to 4.x

Answer (score 44):

**Use**

```
find path/to/dir -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"
```

**Explanation**

1. The first parameter is the directory you want to search.
2. By default `find` does recursion.
3. The `-o` stands for `-or`. So above means search for this wildcard OR this one. If you have only one pattern then no need for `-o`.
4. The quotes around the wildcard pattern are required.

Answer (score 20):

The default way to search for files recursively, and available in most cases is

```
find . -name "filepattern"
```

It starts recursively traversing for filename or pattern from within the current directory where you are positioned. With the [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) command, you can use wildcards, and various switches. To see the full list of options, type

```
man find
```

Or if man pages aren't available at your system:

```
find --help
```

However, there are more modern and faster tools than *find*, which are traversing your whole filesystem and indexing your files. One such common tool is *[locate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix))* or slocate/mlocate. You should check the manual of your OS on how to install it, and once it's installed, it needs to initiate the database. If the install script doesn't do it for you, it can be done manually by typing

```
sudo updatedb
```

And, to use it to look for some particular file, type:

```
locate filename
```

Or, to look for a filename or pattern from within the current directory, you can type:

```
pwd | xargs -n 1 -I {} locate "filepattern"
```

It will look through its database of files and quickly print out path names that match the pattern that you have typed.
To see the full list of locate's options, type:
`locate --help` or `man locate`

Additionally, you can configure locate to update its database on scheduled times via a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job, so a sample cron which updates the database at 1 AM would look like:

```
0 1 * * * updatedb
```

These cron jobs need to be configured by *root*, since *updatedb* needs root privileges to traverse the whole filesystem.

Answer (score 20):

You can use:

```
find . -type f  -name 'text_for_search'
```

If you want use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), use `-iname`:

```
find . -type f  -iname 'text_for_search'
```

Answer (score 15):

For file search

`find / -xdev -name settings.xml`   → the whole computer 
`find ./ -xdev -name settings.xml`  → the current directory and its subdirectories

For files with an extension type:

```
find . -type f -name "*.iso"
```

Answer (score 14):

I am surprised to see that locate is not used heavily when we are to go recursively.

I would first do a locate "$PWD" to get the list of files in the current folder of interest, and then run greps on them as I please.

```
locate "$PWD" | grep -P <pattern>
```

Of course, this is assuming that the updatedb is done and the index is updated periodically. This is much faster way to find files than to run a find and asking it go down the tree.  Mentioning this for completeness.  Nothing against using find, if the tree is not very heavy.

Comment: `locate "$PWD*.mp4"` 

Just to remind that you may be able to skip the `grep`

Answer (score 13):

The following command will list down all the files having the exact name "pattern" (for example) in the current and its sub folders.

`find ./ -name "pattern"`

Comment: Downvote. This repeats a [2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279931/11154841).

Comment: @Brian New answers are expected to provide some new info or an alternative solution, repeating what already has been said is not useful. Just like [when asking a question](/help/how-to-ask), before writing an answer you should search first to make sure your answer will add something useful. Especially when there are lots of other answers, as in such case the possibility of this approaches 0. It's not hard at all, only a single Ctrl+F away.

Answer (score 10):

This will search all the related files in current and sub directories, calculating their line count separately as well as totally:

```
find . -name "*.wanted" | xargs wc -l
```

Answer (score 9):

The below command helps to search for any files

1. Irrespective of case
2. Result *excluding* folders without permission
3. Searching from the root or from the path you like. Change / with the path you prefer.

**Syntax:**

```
find <FromDirectory> -iname '<FileName wild char allowed>'   2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

**Example**

```
find / -iname 'C*.xml' 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

Comment: why on earth do you use grep for that? Just redirect stderr to null `find / -iname '*C*.xml' 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to search special files with a wildcard, you can use the following code:

```
find . -type f -name "*.conf"
```

Suppose, you want to search every .conf files from here:

`.` means search started from here (current place) 
`-type` means type of search item that here is file (f). 
`-name` means you want to search files with ***.conf** names.

Comment: Downvote. These should have been comments under or edits of the [2011 accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905066/11154841).

Answer (score 8):

Try with the `fd` command if installed. [Install instructions](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#installation).

Find all files that start with 'name':

```
fd "name*"
```

This command ignores all `.hidden` and `.gitignore`ed files.

To include `.gitignore`ed files, add the `-I` option as below:

```
fd -I "name*"
```

To include hidden files, add the `-H` option as below:

```
fd -H "name*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ripgrep](https://www.mankier.com/1/rg#--files).

Example:

Search all the filenames contain substring **psql**,

```
rg --files | rg psql
```

Answer (score -4):

With Python>3.5, using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), `.` pointing to your current folder and looking for `.txt` files:

```
 python -c "import glob;[print(x) for x in glob.glob('./**/*txt', recursive=True)]"
```

For older versions of Python, you can install [glob2](https://github.com/miracle2k/python-glob2/)

Comment: _Can someone explain the downvotes? If there is something wrong with my answer, I would like to know what it is._ – This question asks a _native_ solution for Linux shells and you provide an answer in Python. So your answer is off-topic here.

Comment: I don't understand part of your comment @EvgenKo423, since this answer was answered by Katu and not by you.

Comment: @ValerioBozz Look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66128889/revisions). I had quoted their question and answered it.

Comment: _I have seen plenty of questions about `sed` with accepted answers that use `awk` and similar. [...] It feels like this is getting downvoted by people following the trend instead of thinking about it._ – But both `sed` and `awk` are command line tools, while the Python is a full-featured programming language. Downvoting answers costs rep which discourages doing so for no reason, but if you still think it's a voting fraud, have a read of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/578924).
P.S.: Please use comments or [chat] for discussions, they don't belong in answers.