# Recursively look for files with a specific extension

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

I'm trying to find all files with a specific extension in a directory and its subdirectories with my Bash ([Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) LTS (Lucid Lynx) release).

This is what's written in a script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="/home/flip/Desktop"
suffix="in"

browsefolders ()
  for i in "$1"/*;
  do
    echo "dir :$directory"
    echo "filename: $i"
    #    echo ${i#*.}
    extension=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f2`
    echo "Erweiterung $extension"
    if     [ -f "$i" ]; then

        if [ $extension == $suffix ]; then
            echo "$i ends with $in"

        else
            echo "$i does NOT end with $in"
        fi
    elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
    browsefolders "$i"
    fi
  done
}
browsefolders  "$directory"
```

Unfortunately, when I start this script in a terminal, it says:

```
[: 29: in: unexpected operator
```

(with `$extension` instead of `'in'`)

What's going on here, and where's the error?
But this curly brace.

Comment: The error is from a missing '{'

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905054/11725753)

Answer (score 966):

```
find "$directory" -type f -name "*.in"
```

is a bit shorter than that whole thing (and safer. It deals with whitespace in filenames and directory names).

Your script is probably failing for entries that don't have a `.` in their name, making `$extension` empty.

Comment: yes, `find` is recursive by default. you can limit the depths if you want (see the man page).

Comment: I'd like to pass all found files as arguments to a jar-file. How can this be performed?

Comment: @flip: that's a different question. Post a new question, detailing exactly what you'd like to do and what you've tried so far.

Comment: One little correction: use '\*.in' or \\*.in instead of "*.in" because double quotes don't prevent shell expansion. I.e. your script will not work properly if there's a file with .in extension in the current directory.

Comment: @Shnatsel: double quotes do prevent shell expansion. Try it out.

Comment: To follow symbolic links, add `-L` before the path specification, such as: `find -L $directory -type f -name "*.in"`

Comment: Thanks..I would like to know if there is way to list both *.in and *.ini files .. i.e. can we search for multiple extentions.. Also I don't get why ' ' or " " need to be used.. otherwise it says -- no match

Comment: @ChandanChoudhury: `find . -type f -a \( -name '*.in' -o -name '*.ini' \)` ; you need quotes to prevent shell globbing.

Comment: Works nicely. Can I somehow tell it to search in multiple paths? or should I call it for each path separately?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: `man find` is your friend. Put all your paths in the command, works just fine.

Comment: @Mat I don't have Linux. I want to try it on Android, but maybe "man" will work there too. What should be the delimiter between the paths?

Answer (score 277):

```
find {directory} -type f -name '*.extension'
```

**Example:** To find all `csv` files in the current directory and its sub-directories, use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv'
```

Answer (score 64):

The syntax I use is a bit different than what [Mat suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927369/recursively-look-for-files-with-a-specific-extension/5927391#5927391):

```
find $directory -type f -name \*.in
```

(it's one less keystroke).

Comment: Matt's script also won't work if there's a file with .in extension in the current directory, while yours would still work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927369/recursively-look-for-files-with-a-specific-extension#comment22990599_5927391

Comment: @Shnatsel this comment (and hence yours) is plain wrong.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You should provide some reference for your statement, otherwise one could simply argue: "No, you are wrong". But in fact you're right: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Comment: @user1885518: I think that it should be the guy who claims that the script doesn't work who should provide some examples where the script fails. That's what I do when I leave comments where there are broken scripts: it's usually about quotes and filenames containing spaces, newlines, globs, etc., and I specifically explain why it's broken.

Comment: Providing reference is always a good way in a discussion, it does not depend on who was the first. He should, you should.

Answer (score 17):

Without using [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)):

```
du -a $directory | awk '{print $2}' | grep '\.in$'
```

Comment: The `grep` isn't really necessary here. `awk` has regular expressions and could limit its output to values matching a pattern.

Comment: This method is extremely useful if your going through 100s of terabyte. Find command takes too much time to process. This starts immediately.

Comment: `awk|grep` is an anti-pattern. Let awk do the grepping.

Answer (score 14):

Though using `find` command can be useful here, the shell itself provides options to achieve this requirement without any third party tools. The `bash` shell provides an extended glob support option using which you can get the file names under recursive paths that match with the extensions you want.

The extended option is `extglob` which needs to be set using the `shopt` option as below. The options are enabled with the `-s` support and disabled with he `-u` flag. Additionally you could use couple of options more i.e. `nullglob` in which an unmatched glob is swept away entirely, replaced with a set of zero words. And `globstar` that  allows to recurse through all the directories

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob globstar
```

Now all you need to do is form the glob expression to include the files of a certain extension which you can do as below. We use an array to populate the glob results because when quoted properly and expanded, the filenames with special characters would remain intact and not get broken due to word-splitting by the shell.

For example to list all the `*.csv` files in the recursive paths

```
fileList=(**/*.csv)
```

The option `**` is to recurse through the sub-folders and `*.csv` is glob expansion to include any file of the extensions mentioned. Now for printing the actual files, just do

```
printf '%s\n' "${fileList[@]}"
```

Using an array and doing a proper quoted expansion is the right way when used in shell scripts, but for interactive use, you could simply use `ls` with the glob expression as

```
ls -1 -- **/*.csv
```

This could very well be expanded to match multiple files i.e. file ending with multiple extension (i.e. similar to adding multiple flags in `find` command). For example consider a case of needing to get all recursive image files i.e. of extensions `*.gif`, `*.png` and `*.jpg`, all you need to is

```
ls -1 -- **/+(*.jpg|*.gif|*.png)
```

This could very well be expanded to have negate results also. With the same syntax, one could use the results of the glob to exclude files of certain type. Assume you want to exclude file names with the extensions above, you could do

```
excludeResults=()
excludeResults=(**/!(*.jpg|*.gif|*.png))
printf '%s\n' "${excludeResults[@]}"
```

The construct `!()` is a negate operation to not include any of the file extensions listed inside and `|` is an alternation operator just as used in the Extended Regular Expressions library to do an OR match of the globs.

Note that these extended glob support is not available in the POSIX bourne shell and its purely specific to recent versions of `bash`. So if your are considering portability of the scripts running across POSIX and `bash` shells, this option wouldn't be right.

Answer (score 14):

Use:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name "*.in"
```

Answer (score 10):

1. There's a `{` missing after `browsefolders ()`
2. All `$in` should be `$suffix`
3. The line with `cut` gets you only the middle part of `front.middle.extension`. You should read up your shell manual on `${varname%%pattern}` and friends.

I assume you do this as an exercise in shell scripting, otherwise the `find` solution already proposed is the way to go.

To check for proper shell syntax, without running a script, use `sh -n scriptname`.

Answer (score 7):

To find all the `pom.xml` files in your current directory and print them, you can use:

```
find . -name 'pom.xml' -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
find $directory -type f -name "*.in" | grep $substring
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in "${LOCATION_VAR}"/*.zip
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.