# how can I print the name of all files from a folder

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line

I have like 10000 files in a folder and I want to know which one is doublicated.
I like to save only the names of them in a txt file

Is there any way to do it?

My files look like this. as an example

```
..._P2_A1-(01)_....tx
```

For me it is doublicated when I have the first part twice 
`QEX2_P2_A1`

I did try to print it but with no success for example, here is one solution 
[Bash: How to print the filename of the nth file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631016/bash-how-to-print-the-filename-of-the-nth-file-in-a-folder)  or [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash?rq=1)  which did not work for me. I have tried to search it but I could not find any solution

Comment: Two files cannot have the same name in a given dir.

Comment: Now it is less confusing, but it still lacks quite a lot of info. Please provide a [mcve] together with what you tried  so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf + awk` to print all partially duplicated filenames:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | awk -F '_' '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} k in seen{dups[seen[k]]=k; dups[$0]=k}
  {seen[k]=$0} END{for (f in dups) print dups[f] " => " f}'
```

Comment: @nik: or there is no duplicate