# Find similar folder names recursively in bash

Tags: find, pattern-matching

How could I find similar folder names recursively in bash command line?

I don't know specific name, I want all similar folders grouped by similarity. In other words, I need the bash to search each one by all folder names.

I use bash in OS X terminal.

Similar folder means: folders which have at least one same word. For example, below folder names:

"Example"

"John Example"

"Example (200)"

"12 Example"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively look for files with a specific extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927369/recursively-look-for-files-with-a-specific-extension)

Comment: No, It is completely different. I don't know the specific name of folders, I just want to know similar folder names in path.

Comment: Please define "similar folder". Do you want to find all folders with substring "Example"?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, substring of "Example". However I don't want specific name such as "Example". I want the bash to search each one by all folder names.

Comment: I prefer to use R in this case!