# Recursively looking for a list of file types

Tags: bash, search, filter, associative-array

I want to use bash to remove all the files in a directory that aren't in an associative array of file extensions. (i.e. delete all the files in a directory that aren't image files, for example)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927369/recursively-look-for-files-with-a-specific-extension) very clearly answers how to do this for a single file extension, but I'm not sure how to do it for a whole list.

currently I'm doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5247919/2278676)

```
for f in $(find . -type f ! -name '*.png' -and ! -name '*.jpg' ); do rm "$f"; done
```

but it seems ugly to just add a massive list of "-and -name '*.aaa'" inside the parenthesis for every file type.

Is there a way to pass `find` an associate array like

```
declare -A allowedTypes=([*.png]=1 [*.jpg]=1 [*.gif]=1)
```

or will I just need to add a lot of "-and ! -name ___"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of using `find` int the first place is *not* needed. The shell globbing support in `bash` is sufficient enough for this requirement. The `bash` shell provides an extended glob support option using which you can get the file names under recursive paths that don't end with the extensions you want to ignore.

The extended option is `extglob` which needs to be set using the `shopt` option as below. Additionally you could use couple of options more i.e. `nullglob` in which an unmatched glob is swept away entirely, replaced with a set of zero words. And `globstar` that  allows to recurse through all the directories

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob globstar
```

Now all you need to do is form the glob expression to exclude the files of type `*.png`, `*.jpg` and `*.gif` which you can do as below. We use an array to populate the glob results because when quoted properly and expanded, the filenames with special characters would remain intact

```
fileList=(**/!(*.jpg|*.gif|*.png))
```

The option `**` is to recurse through the sub-folders and `!()` is a negate operation to not include any of the file extensions listed inside. Now for printing the actual files, just do

```
printf '%s\n' "${fileList[@]}"
```

If your intentions is for example to remove all the files identified, you don't need to store the glob results in the array. One could use the array approach when writing simple shell scripts which need to use the results of the glob. But for a case of deleting the files, you could use the `rm` command.

At first you could check if the files returned are *as* expected and once you confirmed you could the `rm` on the expression. Use `ls` to see if the files are listed as expected

```
ls -1 -- **/!(*.jpg|*.gif|*.png)
```

and now after confirming the files to delete, do `rm` at your own risk.

```
rm -- **/!(*.jpg|*.gif|*.png)
```

Comment: I had originally said "print" to simplify, but I actually need to remove all of the files that aren't in the extension list, so your final "printf" doesn't actually work for my needs (neither does just saving all the filenames into a list. I've modified my question, can you modify your answer to do removing?

Comment: `globstar` requires `bash` v4 at least, I believe, so macOS users would need to install that since Apple only ships `bash` v3.2 or so.

Comment: What if file, or extension is upper case? Do you have to use all that `[jJ][pP][gG]` nonsense? Or can you use `shopt -s nocaseglob`?

Answer (score 1):

*Assumption*: `allowedTypes` contains only trusted input and only valid suffixes.

The first snippet supports multi-level suffixes like `tar.gz`. It uses `find`, a regular expression and a list of allowed suffixes `allowedTypes`.

```
allowedTypes=(png gif jpg)

# keepTypes='png|gif|jpg'
keepTypes="$(echo "${allowedTypes[@]}" | tr ' ' '|')"

find . -type f -regextype awk ! -iregex '(.*).('"$keepTypes"')' -exec echo rm {} \;
```

If you want to keep your associate array, then you could use the following snippet.
It needs additional work to support multi-level file suffixes.

```
declare -A allowedTypes=([*.png]=1 [*.jpg]=1 [*.gif]=1)

keepTypes="$(echo "${!allowedTypes[@]}" | tr ' ' '|' | tr -d '.*')"
```

It would be nice if there would be a way to replace the separators with a built-in tool instead of `tr` but I found none. `${allowedTypes[@]//\ /test}` did not replace the whitespaces between the items.