# How can I find all specified files in a folder with extension .thrift in shell recursively?

Tags: shell

Directory structure like below :

```
├─thrift_master
   ├─Common
     └─common.thrift
   ├─folder2
     └─f1.thrift
   └─types.thrift
└─update.sh
```

I want to generate python-thrift package by using `thrift -nowarn -gen py`

Here's my attemp using shell, it works for I'm using absolute directory like `Common/*.thrift`, how can I make it work recursively?

```sh
cd `dirname $0`

TMP=thrift_master

#...

cd $TMP

for i in Common/*.thrift *.thrift folder2/*.thrift
do
        thrift  -nowarn -gen py $i
done

echo "update thrift_interface gen files..."
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively look for files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927369/recursively-look-for-files-with-a-specific-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` utility on Unix/Linux systems:

```
cd thrift_master

find . -iname '*.thrift' -print0 |
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    thrift -nowarn -gen py "$file"
done
```

- Using `-print0` option of `find` to get output delimited by NUL character to address filenames with whitespaces / glob characters.
- Correspondingly we need to use `-IFS=` and `-d ''` in `read` to handle filenames separated by NUL character.

PS: If you're `bash` then you can avoid pipeline by using **process substitution**:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    thrift -nowarn -gen py "$file"
done < <(find . -iname '*.thrift' -print0)
```

Comment: thanks for your replying, it works, and could you pls tell the difference between  command `find . -type f -name "*.thrift" | xargs -n 1 thrift  -nowarn -gen py $file
` and yours?

Comment: Actually `xargs` command won't know anything about `$file` variable. Correct command would probably be: `find . -type f -name "*.thrift" | xargs -n 1 thrift -nowarn -gen py`