# Rename multiple files by replacing a particular pattern in the filenames using a shell script

Tags: shell

> Write a simple script that will automatically rename a number of files. As an example we want the file *001.jpg renamed to user defined string + 001.jpg (ex: MyVacation20110725_001.jpg) The usage for this script is to get the digital camera photos to have file names that make some sense.

I need to write a shell script for this. Can someone suggest how to begin?

Comment: I suggest reading the man pages to [mv](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv)

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Comment: good thread : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116753/command-to-mass-rename-files-according-to-pattern

Comment: rename 's/.+(\d{3}:?)\.jpg/string$1.jpg/g' *.jpg

Answer (score 421, accepted):

An example to help you get off the ground.

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed s/IMG/VACATION/)"; done
```

In this example, I am assuming that all your image files contain the string `IMG` and you want to replace `IMG` with `VACATION`.

The shell automatically evaluates `*.jpg` to all the matching files.

The second argument of `mv` (the new name of the file) is the output of the `sed` command that replaces `IMG` with `VACATION`.

If your filenames include whitespace pay careful attention to the `"$f"` notation. You need the double-quotes to preserve the whitespace.

Comment: With bash, you can also redirect from a string: `sed 's/foo/bar/' <<< "$f"`

Comment: Excellent example Susam--this usage also worked for me in MingW to change files named `*-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` to `*.war`, like this: `for i in *.war; do mv ${i} \`echo ${i} | sed 's/-1.0-SNAPSHOT\.war/\.war/'\`; done`

Comment: just to add to this.. you can also use wild card, say for example there is a bunch of files with IMGnnnn.jpg where n is a bunch of nunbers; then you could do something like  s/IMG.*/VACATION\\.jpg/

Comment: @MikeStewart The GNU documentation you have linked to presents many non-POSIX features. See [POSIX.1-2008: § 2.6.2: Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for the POSIX specification on parameter expansion. The `${file//IMG/myVacation}` substitution in the other answer you have linked to does not conform to POSIX. It does not work with `dash`. On Debian, the default `sh` is `dash`. When `dash` encounters `${file//IMG/myVacation}`, it fails with `Bad substitution` error because this syntax does not conform to POSIX.

Comment: @SusamPal Ah, yes, I was aware BASH has many features that are not POSIX compliant. (It says as much in the manual). But I'm glad you clarified and shared a more appropriate link for the example. Thanks!

Comment: It does not work inside a (GNU) Makefile! `mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory` Why?

Comment: @Christoph90 Are you escaping the `$` as `$$` within the `Makefile`? Perhaps it is worth asking a new question with your complete `Makefile`?

Comment: @SusamPal That was exactly the issue, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 214):

You can use **rename** utility to rename multiple files by a pattern. For example following command will prepend string MyVacation2011_ to all the files with jpg extension.

```
rename 's/^/MyVacation2011_/g' *.jpg
```

or

```
rename <pattern> <replacement> <file-list>
```

Comment: But there must be variants of this commands, rename is just like mv on my RedHat 6.5

Comment: This didn't work for me, because I had too many files: `-bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long`.   But I agree it's nice if you have a smaller list

Comment: @ixe013 This rename is perl version, not built-in utility. Follow the guide at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename to install.

Comment: The "Argument list too long" problem can be circumvented by use of `find`:

`find . -name *.jpg -exec rename <pattern> <replacement> {} \;`

This will call rename once per file.

Comment: I noted that in the first approach, if you keep out the `g` flag of the regular expression, it only applies the transform to the first matching entry -- good for testing.

Comment: I need to capture something from the original and place it somewhere else e.g. `something-123.jpg` to `123-something.jpg`?

Comment: @CpILL it uses regex capture groups, and the replacement string will substitue `$<groupNumber>` with the match. e.g. `rename 's/([^-]+)-([^.]+)/$2-$1/g' *`. The pattern `^([^-]+)-([^.]+)` means: from the start of the name, capture 1 or more chars that are NOT `-`, then expect a dash, then capture 1 or more chars that are not `.`. `$1` is the first capture, `$2` is the second.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Btw, I tried to use `rename <pattern> <replacement> <filelist>` today and my "replacement" started with a minus (`-4.6`), so the command complained with `rename: invalid option -- '4'`. Solved it by running `rename -- '<pattern>' '<replacement>' <filelist>`

Answer (score 79):

this example, I am assuming that all your image files begin with "IMG" and you want to replace "IMG" with "VACATION"

solution  : first identified all jpg files and then replace keyword

```
find . -name '*jpg' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 ${0/IMG/VACATION}' {} \;
```

Comment: Best answer as it allow traversal of the directory trees, uses built-in bash utilities and is easily configurable. Also, the example gives the non-destructive test to make sure the changes are correct.

Comment: Just a note here... pretty obvious but worth statting: the `'echo mv $0 ${0/IMG/VACATION}'` portion is the actual command that will be ran against each file found. So, if you leave the `echo` there, it will only echo what it would do. Remove the `echo` command to actually move the files eg. `find . -name '*jpg' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/IMG/VACATION}' {} \; `

Comment: Kudos for including `echo` so users know if it will work or not

Comment: most useful; though you should probably add the note from @dmmd. I actually dumped the output of the echo to  a shell script for inspection then executed that... cuz I'm paranoid.

Answer (score 53):

```
for file in *.jpg ; do mv $file ${file//IMG/myVacation} ; done
```

Again assuming that all your image files have the string "IMG" and you want to replace "IMG" with "myVacation".

With bash you can directly convert the string with [parameter expansion](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion).

Example: if the file is IMG_327.jpg, the `mv` command will be executed as if you do `mv IMG_327.jpg myVacation_327.jpg`. And this will be done for each file found in the directory matching `*.jpg`.

IMG_001.jpg -> myVacation_001.jpg
IMG_002.jpg -> myVacation_002.jpg
IMG_1023.jpg -> myVacation_1023.jpg
etcetera...

Comment: @MikeStewart The GNU documentation you have linked to presents many non-POSIX features. See [POSIX.1-2008: § 2.6.2: Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for the POSIX specification on parameter expansion. The `${file//IMG/myVacation}` substitution in this answer does not conform to POSIX. It does not work with `dash`. On Debian, the default `sh` is `dash`. When `dash` encounters `${file//IMG/myVacation}`, it fails with `Bad substitution` error because this substitution syntax does not conform to POSIX.

Answer (score 13):

```
find . -type f | 
sed -n "s/\(.*\)factory\.py$/& \1service\.py/p" | 
xargs -p -n 2 mv
```

eg will rename all files in the cwd with names ending in "factory.py" to be replaced with names ending in "service.py"

explanation:

1. In the `sed` cmd, the `-n` flag will suppress normal behavior of echoing input to output after the s/// command is applied, and the `p` option on s/// will force writing to output if a substitution is made. Since a sub will only be made on match, sed will only have output for files ending in "factory.py"
2. In the s/// replacement string, we use "`&` " to interpolate the entire matching string, followed by a space character, into the replacement. Because of this, it's vital that our RE matches the entire filename. after the space char, we use "\1service.py" to interpolate the string we gulped before "factory.py", followed by "service.py", replacing it. So for more complex transformations youll have to change the args to s/// (with an re still matching the entire filename)

Example output:

```
foo_factory.py foo_service.py
bar_factory.py bar_service.py
```

3. We use `xargs` with `-n 2` to consume the output of sed 2 delimited strings at a time, passing these to mv (i also put the -p option in there so you can feel safe when running this). voila.

NOTE: If you are facing more complicated file and folder scenarios, [this post explains `find` (and some alternatives) in greater detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard).

Comment: IMO this is the only valid solution. Beautiful, fast and flexible.

Comment: The best, most flexible solution. Especially in environments (like `cygwin`) where `perl replace` (the regex-enabled version of `replace` that is required in some of the above solutions) is not available or hard to come by.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is:

```
for i in *001.jpg
do
  echo "mv $i yourstring${i#*001.jpg}"
done
```

remove `echo` after you have it right.

Parameter substitution with `#` will keep only the last part, so you can change its name.

Comment: This does not allow for recursive file and folder structures and has several other shortcomings. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029320/2228771) by John supersedes this for all but the most trivial scenarios.

Comment: Little addendum to my previous comment: globs now support recursion with the [globstar option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639124). (But this solution is still missing regex replace support).

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment on Susam Pal's answer but if you're dealing with spaces, I'd surround with quotes:

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed s/\ /\-/g`"; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for file in *.jpg;
do
  mv $file $somestring_${file:((-7))}
done
```

You can see "parameter expansion" in `man bash` to understand the above better.