# Find directories with names matching pattern and move them

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a bunch of directories like `001/` `002/` `003/` mixed in with others that have letters in their names.  I just want to grab all the directories with numeric names and move them into another directory.

I try this:

```
file */ | grep ^[0-9]*/ | xargs -I{} mv {} newdir
```

The matching part works, but it ends up moving everything to the `newdir`...

Comment: I update my answer...hope to be helpful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understood correctly but here is at least something to help.

Use a combination of find and xargs to manipulate lists of files.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regex './[0-9]*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' mv "{}" "newdir/{}"
```

Using `-print0` and `-0` and quoting the replacement symbol `{}` make your script more robust. It will handle most situations where non-printable chars are presents. This basically says it passes the lines using a `\0` char delimiter instead of a `\n`.

Comment: @6pool Use `echo` to help you debug complex `xargs` commands. like this `... | xargs echo mv ...`

Answer (score 0):

`mv` is not powerfull enough by itself. It cannot work on patterns.

Try this approach: [Rename multiple files by replacing a particular pattern in the filenames using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840332/rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-a-particular-pattern-in-the-filenames-using-a)

Either use a loop or a `rename` command.

Answer (score 0):

With loop and array,

Your script would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=( $(file */ | grep ^[0-9]*/ | awk -F/ '{print $1}') ) 

for dir in "${DIR[@]}"; do
   mv $dir /path/to/DIRECTORY
done
```