# Copy multiple file from multiple directories with new filename

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, copy, xargs

I want to make a specific copy.
I explain

So here my main folder :

```
Sub-Directory-name-01\filename-01.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-01\filename-02.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-01\filename-03.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-01\special-filename-01.jpg

Sub-Directory-name-02\filename2-01.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-02\filename2-02.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-02\filename2-03.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-02\special-filename2-01.jpg


Sub-Directory-name-02\filename2-01.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-02\filename2-02.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-02\filename2-03.jpg
Sub-Directory-name-02\special-filename2-01.jpg
```

I want to copy all file from all dir and :
- keep original file
- copy 2 times the original file
- add a prefix to the new name
- prefix-01 for first copy
- prefix-02 for second copy
- keep the new files in the same dir as original file

I allready succes with a command to copy 1 time with 1 prefix.
It works in the sub-directory

```
for file in *.jpg; do cp "$file" "prefix-$file"; done
```

I try to do for all sub-dirs but i got an error

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" ! -iname "special-*.jpg" \) | xargs cp -v "$file" "prefix-$file"
```

( yes i exclude a special name )

But i got error :

```
cp: target `./Sub-Directory-name-01/filename-01.jpg' is not a directory
```

i dont know how to solve my problem and how to add the 2nd copy in the cmd.

Thanks

Edit : I havent found any similar question so any answser to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086502/608639), [https://stackoverflow.com/q/6911301/608639](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16541582/608639), [Rename multiple files by replacing a particular pattern in the filenames using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6840332/608639), [Find directories with names matching pattern and move them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22319557/608639), [Rename multiple files shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6911301/608639), etc.

Comment: JWW, It's absolutely not a duplicate of threads you post. I m not even sure you took time to read question and answer.. Thanks to JJO for his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that above `$file` is set **only** by the `for file in ... ; do ... ;done` loop, i.e. in your `xargs` cmdline you were just using the last *leftover* value from the loop.

Some things to consider:

- need to process each file separately => use `xargs -l1` (process each 1 line).
- need to separate `DIR/FILENAME` as the needed command is something like 'cp $DIR/$FILENAME $DIR/prefix-01-$FILENAME' (and prefix-02 also), use `find ... -printf "%h %f\n"` for this
- for each line, need to do couple things (prefix-01,02) => use a *scriptlet* via `sh -c '<scriptlet>'`
- better skip `prefix-0?-*.jpg` files from `find`, to be able to re-run it without "accumulating" copies

A possible implementation would be:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" ! -iname "special-*.jpg"  ! -name "prefix-0?-*.jpg" \) -printf "%h %f\n" | \
xargs -l1 sh -c 'cp -v "$1/$2" "$1/prefix-01-$2"; cp -v "$1/$2" "$1/prefix-02-$2"' --
```

As `xargs` runs `sh -c '<scriptlet>' -- DIR FILE` for each line, the *scriptlet* will properly evaluate `$1` and `$2` respectively.

--jjo

PS: directory separator in Unix-like systems is `/` :)

[Update: fixed to use `%f` instead of `%P`, as per comments below]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to understand what you write.. I test your command and i got an error, it's doubling subdirname :  cp: cannot stat `./Sub-Directory-name-01/Sub-Directory-name-01/filename-01.jpg': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `./Sub-Directory-name-01/Sub-Directory-name-01/filename-01.jpg': No such file or directory

Comment: that's working with :  -printf "%h %f\n" instead of -printf "%h %P\n"