# Change basename of multiple files in a single directory

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I have many files of the form `{a}_{b}_R1.txt` I would like to change the basenames of these files to `{a}.{b}.txt` how would I go about this? I can only find out how to do this with extensions. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files by replacing a particular pattern in the filenames using a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840332/rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-a-particular-pattern-in-the-filenames-using-a)

Comment: What did you try for yourself and fail?

Comment: I tried `mv *_R1.fasta *.fasta` did not remove the `_R1` after that it'd be easier to replace the single `_`

Comment: @JNevill solution doesnt work for me on Mac

Comment: @quantik: Can you give a couple of actual file names and their value to be replaced?

Comment: @Inian Sure. `K_SPF_R1.txt Muc0582_SPF_R1.txt Muc0583_SPF_R1.txt`

Comment: I figure doing two successive for loops may work:

`for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed s/_R1//`"; done`

then 
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed s/_/./`"; done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just a simple loop in the native `bash` shell under `OS X` from terminal, after navigating to the folder containing those text files,

```
# Looping for all the text files in the current 
# directory
for file in *.txt; do
    # Stripping off '_R1' from the file-name
    temp1="${file//_R1/}"
    # Replacing '_' with '.' and renaming the file to the name generated
    temp2="${temp1//_/.}"
    echo "$temp2" "$file"
    #mv -v "$file" "$temp2"
done
```

Remove the line with `echo` and uncomment the `mv` once you find the names are changed accordingly.

```
for file in *.txt; do temp1="${file//_R1/}"; temp2="${temp1//_/.}"; mv -v "$file" "$temp2"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

This works as well:

`for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "echo $f | sed s/_R1//"; done then for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "echo $f | sed s/_/./";`

Comment: You don't need `sed` or any third party tools for this, can be done with the native `bash` features alone