# How to rename partly the downloaded file using wget?

Tags: wget, file-rename

I'd like to download many files (about 10000) from ftp-server. Names of the files are too long. I'd like to save them only with the date in names. For example:  `ABCDE201604120000-abcde.nc`   I prefer to be    `20160412.nc` 
Is it possible?

Comment: How do you download the files? Recursively, or do you use some bash scripting?

Comment: wget -cr -np -S -P  /home/MyFolderDownloads/   http:/NameOfTheSite.domain/AFolder/*.nc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `wget` provides similar functionality, nevertheless with `curl`, one can profit from the relatively rich [syntax](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) it provides in order to specify the URL of interest. For example:

```
curl \
    "https://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/SOTMEU2014/[53-54].{mp3,mp4}" \
    -o "file_#1.#2"
```

will download files `53.mp3, 53.mp4, 54.mp3, 54.mp4`. The output file is specified as `file_#1.#2` - here, `#1` is replaced by `curl` with the value of the sequence `[53-54]` corresponding to the file being downloaded. Similarly, `#2` is replace with either `mp3` or `mp4`. Thus, e.g., `53.mp3` will be saved as `file_53.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

[ewcz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48355228/694162) works fine if you can enumerate the file names as shown in the post. However, if the filenames are difficult to enumerate, for example, because the integers are sparsely populated, this solution would result in a lot of `404 Not Found` requests.

If this is the case, then it is probably better to download all the files recursively, as you have shown, and rename them afterwards. If the file names follow a fixed pattern, you can select the substring from the original name and use it as the new name. In the given example, the new file names start at position 5 and are 8 characters long. The following bash command renames all `*.nc` files in the current directory.

```
for f in *.nc; do mv "$f" "${f:5:8}.nc" ; done
```

If the filenames do not follow a fix pattern and might vary in length, you can use more complex pattern substitution using `sed`, see [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840332/rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-a-particular-pattern-in-the-filenames-using-a) for an example.