# Is it possible to change extensions to all files in one folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: rename

I want to change extensions from `mp3` to `mp4` to all files in one directory (folder). Is it possible or I need to write a script to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename multiple files by replacing a particular pattern in the filenames using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840332/rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-a-particular-pattern-in-the-filenames-using-a)

Comment: No, actually is not. How do I rename music files `mp3` to `mp4`?

Answer (score 1):

You could imagine something like this:

```sh
for f in *.mp3; do
    mv $f ${f/.mp3/.mp4}
done
```

The part with `${x/a/b}` is a string substitution in bash, it replaces a for b in x