# How can I find a file/directory that could be anywhere on linux command line?

Tags: linux, bash, find, ksh, locate

Ideally, I would be able to use a program like

```
find [file or directory name]
```

to report the paths with matching filenames/directories. Unfortunately this seems to only check the current directory, not the entire folder.

I've also tried locate and which, but none find the file, even though I know its on the computer somewhere.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, as `find -name "filename"` finds files recursively in the current working directory.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, the file may not be in the current working directory. It could be anywhere on the computer

Comment: find /<directory mount point/part> -name <filename>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding a file on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459526/finding-a-file-on-linux)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

"Unfortunately this seems to only check the current directory, not the entire folder".  Presumably you mean it doesn't look in subdirectories.  To fix this, use `find -name "filename"`

If the file in question is not in the current working directory, you can search your entire machine via

```
find / -name "filename"
```

This also works with stuff like `find / -name "*.pdf"`, etc.  Sometimes I like to pipe that into a grep statement as well (since, on my machine at least, it highlights the results), so I end up with something like

```
find / -name "*star*wars*" | grep star
```

Doing this or a similar method just helps me instantly find the filename and recognize if it is in fact the file I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, will this work for partial filenames?

Comment: Yes, provided you use the asterisk.  Note that it is case sensitive.  If I have a file called STARTUP I want to find, `find / -name "*ART*"` will find it.  note that `find / -name "*art*"` will NOT locate that file, since "art" is lower case, whereas "STARTUP" is upper case

Comment: @johncorser you should also be able to use some sort of RE to find what you need

Comment: Good to know! I didn't realize I could use regular expressions with find!

Comment: it is surprisingly slow. I have a scratch linux machine on EC2, and it can't find file in a minute.

Answer (score 28):

To get rid of permission errors (and such), you can redirect stderr to nowhere

```
find / -name "something" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thankyou, this _actually_ answers the question "how do I find a file that could be anywhere". For linux noobs like me that don't understand standard folder structures and aren't interested in typing three hundred `cd` commands to find the file, and aren't interested in searching through hundreds of permission denied lines, this is the perfect answer. For my specific case I'm trying to find the sqlcmd tool within the SQL Server linux

Answer (score 9):

The `find` command will take long time, the fastest way to search for file is using `locate` command, which looks for file names (and path) in a indexed database (updated by command `updatedb`).

The result will appear immediately with a simple command:

```
locate {file-name-or-path}
```

If the command is not found, you need to install `mlocate` package and run `updatedb` command first to prepare the search database for the first time.

More detail here: https://medium.com/@thucnc/the-fastest-way-to-find-files-by-filename-mlocate-locate-commands-55bf40b297ab

Comment: have used both the find and locate solutions, and i can confirm locate is much faster

Comment: `find` didn't output anything and took a long time to execute. `locate` gave out the file's location instantly.

Answer (score 8):

If need to find nested in some dirs:

```
find / -type f -wholename "*dirname/filename"
```

Or connected dirs:

```
find / -type d -wholename "*foo/bar"
```

Comment: How do we use both files and directories in a single find command?  i am trying something like this "find / -maxdepth 1 -type d,f " but I get a message on command line saying - " find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this comment will help you to find out your local & server file path using terminal

```
 find "$(cd ..; pwd)" -name "filename"
```

Or just you want to see your Current location then run

```
 pwd "filename"
```