# Path to repository in travis

Tags: android, travis-ci

I am not able to locate the path to my repo (that is cloned) in travis. When I perform `ls`, there is no output. I have tried `ls ~/username/repo` and `ls ~/repo` but get `no such file or directory`

Some background: I am integrating my android app with travis-ci. I want to create a new `.java` file, before build in travis. Since this file is private and added to `.gitignore` and is on build machines only. I intend to add content to this file by using encrypted environment variable feature.

Any custom command doesn't show the output. Not even `echo`. There is an environment variable $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR but not sure how to use it

Comment: `~/username` doesn't make sense... Try using `find / -name repo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find a file/directory that could be anywhere on linux command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655436/how-can-i-find-a-file-directory-that-could-be-anywhere-on-linux-command-line)

Comment: Whenever i execute a custom command i do not see its output. not even `echo`. So this wouldn't work. I've tried looking [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) with the variable $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR , but still failing.

Comment: Sounds like a Linux issue, not a Travis issue

Comment: He is trying to execute a bash command from a yaml file and asking for a specific path for a specific vendor, it's not a duplicated in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a syntax issue, be sure you use [it](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) like [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6122#issuecomment-239073557), it normally works:

> **TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR**: The absolute path to the directory where the
>   repository being built has been copied on the worker.

`- ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/`

`- ls ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/`

Also check the lines below from [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2848#issuecomment-64183874) that links to this [build](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/builds/42187133) and [travis.yml](https://github.com/ardock/iosched/blob/1f793d83ed995dbc72034e519f2c1bbd9fb13b81/.travis.yml#L60) (it works as shown [here](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/jobs/42187139#L4083)):

> ```
> env:
>   global:
>     - ANDROID_HOME=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/android-sdk
>     - PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/:${PATH}
>
> before_install:
>   - cp -R /usr/local/android-sdk-23.0.2 ./android-sdk
> ```
>
> ... You could create a ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/.travis-ci folder and save
>   there all the stuff so we can custom it.

```
  # Comment out the lines below to show system image properties
  - 'echo ${ANDROID_HOME}/system-images/${AVD_TARGET_DIR}/${AVD_TAG}/${AVD_ABI}'
  - 'ls ${ANDROID_HOME}/system-images/${AVD_TARGET_DIR}/${AVD_TAG}/${AVD_ABI} -al || true'
  - 'cat ${ANDROID_HOME}/system-images/${AVD_TARGET_DIR}/${AVD_TAG}/${AVD_ABI}/build.prop || true'

  - echo 'DEFAULT SCRIPTS'
  # Comment out the lines below to check default android scripts and PATH
  - echo "$PATH"
  - ls /usr/local/bin -Al
  - cat /usr/local/bin/android-accept-licenses
  - cat /usr/local/bin/android-update-sdk
  - cat /usr/local/bin/android-wait-for-emulator
```