# How to send E-mail in laravel 5 (without Swiftmailer)?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm getting the `Swift_TransportException` error connecting to `tcp://send.one.com:465` (timed out). I tried on other Hosting server it is working.

I need help to resolve this issue with timing out, or sending mail other ways (other than Swift Mailer, which is not supported on my server).

Comment: That kind of implies that something is being blocked by that first hosting provider (possibly a blanket block on port 465?)? So using another lib won't necessarily help.

Comment: try port 25 or 587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a [great write-up](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail) on using some other mail drivers that are offered / supported, and tuts+ has a [good guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-emails-in-laravel--cms-30046) on implementing this information.

The first step from this, would be your modifications to the mail configuration file for Laravel which will be the driver, and sendmail settings sort of like so:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sendmail'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

From reading those and tweaking those settings you can avoid Swift Mailer and get some emails out.

Comment: I changed the information but the result is same :(

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: using "sendmail" driver i got this error "Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]"

Comment: Using a tool like locate you can find out where your sendmail is, and use that path instead.

Comment: how to I can locate the path?

Comment: You can use a tool like [locate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7459535/1843510) or [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7459540/1843510)

Comment: please visit this [link](http://lukiomedia.fi/php.php) i  have run phpinfo() in this file in my hosting.

Comment: If you search for the variable [`sendmail_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) you'll see it's value: `/usr/sbin/b1sendmail`