# Where are PersistentStateComponent's state stored?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I created PersistentStateComponent which looks like this

```
    @State(name = "MyState", storages = [Storage("my_state.xml")])
    class MyStatePersistence : PersistentStateComponent<MyState> {
      ...
    }
```

and I registered it in plugin.xml:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <applicationService serviceImplementation="com.example.MyStatePersistence"/>
</extensions>
```

I can't figure out where is file `my_state.xml`, which I specified. Is it located in project or what?

Comment: The best place for such questions would be https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Comment: For my sandbox IDE I usually find them in `build/idea-sandbox/config/options`.

Comment: @Abby ok, but if I install plugin on real project, I can't find this file anywhere

Comment: also I find out that in case of project service state's file is located in .idea directory, but for application service I don't see the file

Comment: On linux they seem to be in `~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/options` (with IJ installed via the Toolbox that is). If it's not there, maybe see if running `find -iname "my_state.xml"` in your home directory can find it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two kind of services, and both store their data in different locations.

1. A project service stores its xml file in the `.idea` directory that you find inside the root of the IDE project (or possible module when working with IntelliJ).
2. An application service stores its xml file in the `options` directory, which is located in the [configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory).
   In the sandbox IDE, this is `build/idea-sandbox/config/options`.

To summarize, on Linux, you can find the `my_state.xml` in `~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/options` (for the latest IntelliJ version).

---

For similar situations in the future (on Linux) you could [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7459540/6629569) the file by running `find . -name "my_state.xml"` in your home directory.