# Find all files with name containing string

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, locate

I have been searching for a command that will return files from the current directory which contain a string in the filename. I have seen `locate` and `find` commands that can find files beginning with something `first_word*` or ending with something `*.jpg`.

How can I return a list of files which contain a string in the filename?

For example, if `2012-06-04-touch-multiple-files-in-linux.markdown` was a file in the current directory.

How could I return this file and others containing the string `touch`? Using a command such as `find '/touch/'`

Comment: This question has more answers here: [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905054/11725753)

Answer (score 458, accepted):

Use `find`:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*" -print`

It will find all files in the current directory (delete `maxdepth 1` if you want it recursive) containing "string" and will print it on the screen.

If you want to avoid file containing ':', you can type:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*" ! -name "*:*" -print`

If you want to use `grep` (but I think it's not necessary as far as you don't want to check file content) you can use:

`ls | grep touch`

But, I repeat, `find` is a better and cleaner solution for your task.

Comment: @Dru, if you want it 'shorter' you can avoid `-print` as this is the default behaviour and `.` as this is the default folder where it checks.

Comment: Awesome. I see myself using this a lot. I will take your `-print` and `.` removal suggestions, make it a command, and try to pass `*string*` in as a command line argument.

Comment: `find . -name "*string*"` Works great too. Removing `.` throws an error on my end. Thanks again @Zagorax.

Comment: Just an observation, the above command complained about the position of `-maxdepth` argument better to move it before `-name` as @Sunil Dias mentioned

Comment: I have `find *.jpg -name "*from*" -print` which works for a given directory. How can I make search recursively? I've tried `-maxdepth`.

Comment: bro maxdepth does down only 1 step lol that's silly. Might as well use -r or do like maxdepth 9000 to really go all the way down, no? Other than that, thanks for the great response

Comment: It would be better if you could mention what each of the option for find mean.

Comment: You might want to ignore case with  
`ls | grep -i touch`

Answer (score 26):

Use grep as follows:

```
grep -R "touch" .
```

`-R` means recurse. If you would rather not go into the subdirectories, then skip it.

`-i` means "ignore case". You might find this worth a try as well.

Comment: Great. I noticed that some file contents follow a `:`. Is there anyway to withhold that? Using an option perhaps?

Comment: Try: `grep -R "touch" . | cut -d ":" -f 2`

Comment: That seems to only produce the contents of the files. You essentially answered my question though, I can try to do some digging for withholding the contents.

Comment: Ah... you only need the file names? Run :`grep -R "touch" . | cut -d ":" -f 1`  (sorry must have misread you).

Comment: Thanks @carlspring this is interesting. `grep` either returns files with contents and filenames containing `touch` or contents containing `touch`, I'm not sure which is the case, yet. Of the list of files returned, half contain `touch` in the title and the other half conatains `touch` in the body, not the title. Just realized this.

Comment: `grep` scans files for a certain pattern. The output is: `foo.txt: some text matching your pattern` -- it basically outputs the line where it found the match.

Comment: They asked for file name containing the string not the actual content of file.

Comment: @sahu, well you can always further process this by appending `| cut -d ":" -f 1`, so I don't see the need for the downvote.

Comment: Won't work for binary files like in my case. Also please edit your answer that will help future readers instead of digging in the comments section.

Answer (score 7):

The `-maxdepth` option should be before the `-name` option, like below.,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "string" -print
```

Comment: You have to put * before and after the "string".

Answer (score 4):

```
find $HOME -name "hello.c" -print
```

This will search the whole `$HOME` (i.e. `/home/username/`) system for any files named “hello.c” and display their pathnames:

```
/Users/user/Downloads/hello.c
/Users/user/hello.c
```

However, it will not match `HELLO.C` or `HellO.C`. To match is case insensitive pass the `-iname` option as follows:

```
find $HOME -iname "hello.c" -print
```

Sample outputs:

```
/Users/user/Downloads/hello.c
/Users/user/Downloads/Y/Hello.C
/Users/user/Downloads/Z/HELLO.c
/Users/user/hello.c
```

Pass the `-type f` option to only search for files:

```
find /dir/to/search -type f -iname "fooBar.conf.sample" -print
find $HOME -type f -iname "fooBar.conf.sample" -print
```

The `-iname` works either on GNU or BSD (including OS X) version find command. If your version of find command does not supports `-iname`, try the following syntax using `grep` command:

```
find $HOME | grep -i "hello.c"
find $HOME -name "*" -print | grep -i "hello.c"
```

OR try

```
find $HOME -name '[hH][eE][lL][lL][oO].[cC]' -print
```

Sample outputs:

```
/Users/user/Downloads/Z/HELLO.C
/Users/user/Downloads/Z/HEllO.c
/Users/user/Downloads/hello.c
/Users/user/hello.c
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is at the beginning of the name, you can do this

```
$ compgen -f .bash
.bashrc
.bash_profile
.bash_prompt
```

Comment: `compgen` is not an appropriate hammer for this nail. This little-used tool is designed to list *available commands*, and as such, it lists files in the *current* directory (which could be scripts) and it can neither recurse nor look past the beginning of a file name nor search file contents, making it mostly useless.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the many solutions already provided is making use of the glob `**`.  When you use `bash` with the option `globstar` (`shopt -s globstar`) or you make use of `zsh`, you can just use the glob `**` for this.

```
**/bar
```

does a recursive directory search for files named `bar` (potentially including the file `bar` in the current directory). Remark that this cannot be combined with other forms of globbing within the same path segment; in that case, the `*` operators revert to their usual effect.

Note that there is a subtle difference between `zsh` and `bash` here. While `bash` will traverse soft-links to directories, `zsh` will not. For this you have to use the glob `***/` in `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -exec grep -lR "{test-string}" {} \;
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for low quality. Please explain what your proposed changes do.

Comment: I wonder why, because that's the best answers of all the above.

Answer (score -3):

```
grep -R "somestring" | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

Comment: This appears to be an answer to a different question - but because you've provided no explanation, that isn't obvious to the asker or to anyone else.