# Linux- how to find a file with a certain string in its name?

Tags: linux, string, file

If I want to find all files with the string "test" in their name, how do I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - Find Files with Name Containing String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328988/linux-find-files-with-name-containing-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "test" -print
```

or

```
find . -type f -name "*test*"
```