# AIX: Find Files with name containing specific string and add those to a list

Tags: list, find, filenames, string-matching, aix

We need to find files in a directory with name containing a specific string and  add them in a list.

Suppose we create list containing files names in a specific directory containing string `ABC`.

Tried this one:

```
file_list=()
str="ABC"
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find . -name "*$str*" -print0)
echo "Files getting appended: ${file_list[@]}"
```

If the directory contain files:

```
ABC.txt, ABCD.txt, XYZ.txt, WXYZ.txt
```

Then expected output of the above snippet should be:

```
Files getting appended: ABC.txt ABCD.txt
```

Getting error message in AIX:

```
find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option.
```

Got a related post which works for [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328988/linux-find-files-with-name-containing-string) but got no luck in AIX.

Any help will really be appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, AIX!find doesn't support `-print0`. Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

file_list=()

touch xABCy
touch 'x ABC y'

str="ABC"

while IFS='\n' read -r file ; do
    file_list+=("$file")
done < <(find . -name "*$str*")

for i in "${file_list[@]}"; do
    printf '\"%s\"\n' "$i"
done
```

result:

```
"./x ABC y"
"./xABCy"
```

Comment: Collecting the results into a hash so you can loop over the hash is kind of funny. Just print in the first loop and don't collect the values.

Comment: Sure, the second loop is only there for debugging: it proves that filenames-with-spaces are processed correctly. The actual script is supposed to do some actual work with `file_list`

Comment: I'm pointing this out because needlessly collecting things into variables is a common anti-pattern. If you don't need random access (go back, see how many you collected, compare the file names m*n, skip two, etc) you don't want or need an array here.