# Searching for a user defined file in linux

Tags: c++, python, linux, bash

I have the task of creating a search program in python (or c++ or bash) I'm really not that experienced when it comes to coding so if this isn't on the right track at all, sorry!

The user will need to type in a keyword I.E "Report" and the function will need to look through all directories for files with the name of "report". This script I've made up here seems to work up until line 5. Could anyone help me out? Thank you!

```
import os

keyword = raw_input ("What would you like to search for?")

os.chdir("/home/noob")

for files in os.listdir("."):

  if files(keyword):

     print files
```

Comment: Can't you use the `find` command?

Comment: Sharing the link.
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're getting a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. That's because `os.listdir` returns a list of files.

What you want is to do one of the following:

```
if keyword in files: # for an exact match
```

Or

```
for filename in files:
    if keyword.lower() in filename.lower(): #for case insensitive searching
```

Comment: So after adding that in, I take it i'll need to define files to a directory like files = /home/noob

Comment: Aha brilliant it works! How easy would it be to add in where the files are located? So it tells you the directory it is in. I've obviously set it to look in /home/noob but say the file was in noob/documents/office/ how could i get the program to show me this?

Comment: Check out the `os` module and `os.path` (your favorite search engine should help out there). Especially of interest should be `os.path.abspath`. (Also, `>>> help(os.path.abspath)`, once you've done `import os`.