# Delete .DS_STORE files in current folder and all subfolders from command line on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, command-line

I understand I can use `find . -name ".DS_Store"` to [find all the .DS_Store files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard)  in the current folder and all subfolders. But how could I delete them from command line simultaneously? I found it's really annoying to switch back and forth to all folders and delete it one by one.

Comment: It's odd ya' know - this voting system I mean. On June 10, 2022, this is a highly-upvoted (159 upvotes) question, and the "top 5" answers have 408 net upvotes. But the [only answer that looks at this question in the broader context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69836867/5395338) gets less than 1% of the total net upvotes.

Comment: Related: how to prevent them from being created `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true` (and reboot)

Answer (score 433, accepted):

`find` can do that. Just add `-delete`:

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete
```

Extend it even further to also print their relative paths

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -print -delete
```

For extra caution, you can exclude directories and filter only for files

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -type f -delete
```

Comment: You need to fix file name case to be **".DS_Store"**, if used ".DS_STORE" it will not work as file names are case sensitive.

Comment: @AmrLotfy That's not actually true, the default mac file system is case insensitive

Comment: For extra caution, I usually exclude directories like this: `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete`

Comment: I would add this line to my .bashrc_profile, to clean the files every time I start the shell. How do I make it less verbose, or totaly quiet?

Comment: @Danijel in general, you can append `2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null` to a unix command to make it quiet.

Comment: A bit late but I made an open-source script you can call from the current directory (adapt your path depending on where you save the script.
Available on [Github](https://github.com/barracudapps/scripts/blob/main/rmDSStore.sh)

Answer (score 70):

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -print -delete
```

This will delete all the files named `.DS_Store` in the current path while also displaying their relative paths

Comment: @kelin uh, how is this a link-only answer when there is no link?

Comment: @ppperry, this is automatic message from the review. I voted to delete you answer, because it doesn't add anything important comparing to the accepted one.

Comment: I like the addition of `-print` here

Answer (score 14):

Here is how to remove recursively the `.DS_Store` file

Open up Terminal
In the command line, go to the location of the folder where all files and folders are:

```
cd to/your/directory
```

Then finally, type in the below command:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

Press Enter

Cheers!!

Comment: Proliferating `cd` superstition is doing the community a disservice. Just provide the name of the directory as the first argument to `find` instead of `.`. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 12):

You can also use extended globbing (`**`):

```
rm -v **/.DS_Store
```

in zsh, bash 4 and similar shells (if not enabled, activate by: `shopt -s globstar`).

Comment: I found the problem to be a .DS_Store file in the navigation folder

```grep -r "\x00"  app/src/main/res``` and
```rm -v **/.DS_Store```

That solved the problem

Answer (score 11):

The best way to do this cleanly is using:

```
find . -type f \( -name ".DS_Store" -o -name "._.DS_Store" \) -delete -print 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

This removes the files, hides "permission denied" errors (while keeping other errors), printing out a clean list of files removed.

Answer (score 11):

All the answers above work but there is a bigger problem if one is using mac and still on mac. The described lines **do** delete all the `DS_Store` files but **Finder recreates them immediately again** because that is the default behaviour. You can read about how this all works [here](https://appletoolbox.com/mac-os-x-how-to-remove-ds_store-files/). To quote from there if you are on mac, you should remove them only if you really need:

> If you don’t have a particular reason to delete these .DS_Store files (windows sharing might be a solid reason,) it’s best to leave them “as is.” There’s no performance benefit in deleting .DS_Store files. They are harmless files that don’t usually cause any problems. Remember that the .DS_Store file saves your personalized folder settings, such as your icon arrangement and column sortings. And that’s why you normally don’t want to delete them but rather HIDE them.

If you really do, there is one more way which was not mentioned here:

`sudo find / -name “.DS_Store” -depth -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: `"Finder recreates them..."`  Good point - I was thinking the same thing as I read through all the fine answers here... it's like killing ants: there are always more of them!  In my case, I'm trying to delete `.DS_Store` files that are in my NAS-housed music library - the result of lazy copying and/or `rsync`ing over the years.

Comment: Plus one, if you do an ordinary `ls` the file will not be listed as it is hidden.