# Ubuntu command to find file given filename

Tags: file, ubuntu

I'm trying to find a file called `mynet1`, and I cant located it in my `src` folder and want to search all the possible files in my system for it. What is a Ubuntu command to find a file given its `filename` that could be anywhere in my `/root` and beyond?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard)

Answer (score 5):

To find a file by name, type:

```
find <path> -name "<query>"
```

You can learn a lot here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps#finding-by-name

Answer (score 0):

Note that Midnight Commander (mc) can search for file names (and text), run it from the command prompt, navigate to the top directory of interest and press F9 C F.

To install:

```
sudo aptitude install mc
```