# How do I open multiple remote files with sublime text 3?

Tags: ssh, sublimetext3

I am currently using rsub (rmate for sublime text 3) to open remote files locally.

```
rmate myFile1.txt
```

will open a single local tab.

But when I try to open multiple remote files:

```
rmate myFile*
```

still only a single local tab opens with a single remote file. 
How do I open multiple files at once with * ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rmate does not support directories, as the error says:

```
$ rmate ~/Folder
/home/me/Folder is a directory and rmate is unable to handle directories.
```

---

You could 'find' your files with [`find`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard) and pass them to `rmate`;

For example, use `find` to [recursively find all files in current directory and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard) and use [`-exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec) to open each item found with `rmate`

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec rmate {} \;
```

Use the `find` command without the `-exec rmate {} \;` part to just show the result;

```
$ find .
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./folder/file1.txt
./folder/file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, but can you explain your solution?

Comment: Please see my edit, I hope it's clear, please follow the links