# How to find a file in the git cloned gnuradio installation?

Tags: git, gnuradio

I need to pull out mpsk_receiver_cc.cc (or mpsk_receiver_cc.h) for the implementation of a member function mpsk_receiver_cc(...). I know it is in gnuradio/digital/ folder. How could I find the path for this folder in order to pull out the script for mpsk_receiver_cc.cc (or mpsk_receiver_cc.h)?

My gnuradio workspace is installed via source. Therefore, all the codes should be in my machine.

I know this should be a linux command, but I couldn't succeed after several tries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard)

Comment: still no .cc file

Comment: Then apparently your assumption "I know it is in gnuradio/digital/ folder" is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the right repository:

- [`gnuradio/gnuradio`](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio) has deprecated and removed MPSK receiver in [issue 1083](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/1083), so no more `gr-digital/include/gnuradio/digital/mpsk_receiver_cc.h` there.
- [`n-west/gnuradio-volk`](https://github.com/n-west/gnuradio-volk) does have a [`digital` folder](https://github.com/n-west/gnuradio-volk/tree/master/gr-digital/include/gnuradio/digital) with [`gr-digital/include/gnuradio/digital/mpsk_receiver_cc.h`](https://github.com/n-west/gnuradio-volk/blob/master/gr-digital/include/gnuradio/digital/mpsk_receiver_cc.h) in it, and a [`gr-digital/lib/mpsk_receiver_cc_impl.cc`](https://github.com/n-west/gnuradio-volk/blob/master/gr-digital/lib/mpsk_receiver_cc_impl.cc)

Comment: My question is closely related to the gnuradio file structure. I myself has gone back to everything in this area, and figured out what I need is actually in mpsk_receiver_cc_impl.cc. Thank you