# Find non empty directories with condition on their names in linux

Tags: linux, directory

There's a directory that has several subdirectories. These subdirectories' names are the date that the subdirectory was created. Now I want to list the subdirectories created in 'June' of 2021 and are not empty, so their names all contain this: 202106*.
How can I do this?
The command I use to list non-empty directories is this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d
```

But I don't know how to set the name condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

The name is specified by `-name`

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d -name '202106*'
```

For more information read the [find man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 1):

suggesting

```
find . -type d -path "*202106*" -not -empty
```