Finding .crx file for Chrome Adblock Extension for Selenium script
I'm trying to locate the .crx file for a Chrome extension in order to run it as a part of a Selenium script. I know the file location of the Chrome extension, but cannot find the crx file inside the directory - where would i find this to put in the script?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard
